# Rails 4 + HTML: Combine form responses to generate 1 string entry

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a question on a form with 15 checkboxes.  I would like to take all items that are "checked" and combine the labels into a string that is entered into my database.  I would rather not make a separate DB entry for every checkbox and selecting individuals on this field is not important, I simply need to record the response.

Is there an easy way to combine these and make that the value entered into the DB?

The following displays right, but I'm not sure how to actually submit the correct information.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <div class="field">
            <div class="input check_boxes optional remote_issues">
                <label style="display:block; padding-bottom: 1em" class="check_boxes optional">Which of the following pevent you from reaching your desired weight?</label>

                <% boxes = ["Lack of Knowledge", "Physical Limitations", "Lack of Social Support", "Hunger", "Cravings", "Frequent Travel", "Social Events", "No Time", "Erratic schedule", "Finances", "Family Habits", "Stress", "Hormonal Issues", "Medications", "Illness", "Poor Sleep", "Health Conditions", "Age", "Slow Metabolism", "Alcohol", "No Exercise", "Emotional Eating", "Food Preferences", "Other"] %>

                <% boxes.each do |box| %>
                    <%= render "health_intake", name: box %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_health_intake Partial**

```
<span class="checkbox col-xs-3">
    <label for="remote_issues_lack_of_knowledge">
        <input type="checkbox" value=#{<%= name %>} name="remote[issues][]" class="check_boxes optional" style="margin-right:1em"><%= name %>
    </label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just join the values in your controller for that parameter array:

```
values = params[:issues].join
```

Furthermore, add a comma or something to the join method so you can split them later:

```
values = params[:issues].join(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an Issue model where you store "Lack of Knowledge", etc. Then a join model FooIssue (assuming Foo is the model in your form above).

FooIssue belongs_to :foo and belongs_to :issue. Foo has_many :foo_issues and has_many :issues, through: :foo_issues. Foo accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo_issues.

In your form you display all issues as checkboxes. Issues that are checked get passed back to Foo as nested foo_issues attributes.

With this approach, rather than a serialized approach - which I think is where you were going - you can get better statistics around issues. "What percentage of people say 'Frequent Travel' is an issue?" Things like that.